# HTML5 App on Windows 8 which cannot be closed

Tags: html, windows-8, lockscreen, kiosk-mode

I want to create a HTML5 Application on a Windows 8 Computer which provides product information for a user in the store. Does anyone know if it is possible to set up the windows 8 in a such away, that the user cannot exit the HTML5 App?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible on Windows 8; the soon to be released Windows 8.1 has a "Kiosk Mode", which seems to be what you are looking for.  From [Windows 8.1 kiosk mode locks systems to a single app](http://www.geek.com/microsoft/windows-8-1-kiosk-mode-locks-systems-to-a-single-app-1552963/):

> Generally speaking, kiosk mode is something that’s intended for use in corporate and shared computing settings — like public information terminals. It would, for example, make an excellent way to lock a point-of-sale terminal in to the “cash register” app and prevent would-be procrastinators from tabbing out and surfing the web.